# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'View' of undefined RequireJS Optimizer Backbone

Tags: cordova, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm having some issue trying to get my Phonegap app written using RequireJS, BackboneJS and various over libraries to work after using r.js.

Everything works fine before optimization however afterwards I'm getting the following error in my main-build.js

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'View'

Below is my require config

```
require.config({
baseUrl: 'lib',
paths: {
    domReady        :   'require/domReady',
    text            :   'require/text',
    async           :   'require/async',
    jquery          :   'jquery/jquery',
    jqmconfig       :   'jqm/jqm-config',
    jqm             :   'jqm/jquery.mobile',
    underscore      :   'underscore/underscore',
    backbone        :   'backbone/backbone',
    jqmaps          :   'google/jquery.ui.map',
    router          :   '../app/router',
    models          :   '../app/models',
    collections     :   '../app/collections',
    views           :   '../app/views',
    templates       :   '../app/templates',
    app             :   '../app/app'
},
shim: {
    underscore: {
        exports     :   '_'
   },
   backbone: {
       deps         :   ['jquery', 'jqmconfig', 'jqm', 'underscore'],
       exports      :   'Backbone'
  },
  jqmconfig         :   ['jquery'],
  jqm               :   ['jquery','jqmconfig'],
  jqmaps            :   ['jqm']
}});
```

this is my bootstrap

```
require(
[
    'app', 'domReady', 'jqmconfig'
], 

function(app, domReady){

    domReady(function() {
        // On device ready initialize the app code
    });
});
```

and here is my build.js

```
({
baseUrl: 'lib',
paths: {
    domReady        :   'require/domReady',
    text            :   'require/text',
    async           :   'require/async',
    jquery          :   'jquery/jquery',
    jqmconfig       :   'jqm/jqm-config',
    jqm             :   'jqm/jquery.mobile',
    underscore      :   'underscore/underscore',
    backbone        :   'backbone/backbone',
    jqmaps          :   'google/jquery.ui.map',
    router          :   '../app/router',
    models          :   '../app/models',
    collections     :   '../app/collections',
    views           :   '../app/views',
    templates       :   '../app/templates',
    app             :   '../app/app',
    main            :   '../app/main', 
},
name: 'main',
out: 'app/main-build.js'})
```

Anything glaringly obvious?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shim-config should be dublicated in `build.js` file, so `r.js` can properly include shim dependencies into `app/main-build.js`. You can simply duplicate your shim in `build.js` or better specify [mainConfigFile](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#mainConfigFile) option, so your `paths` and `shim` could only be listed in one place.